# I was faced the problem related to pymesh

Tags: python, pip, pymesh

this is my code...
import pymesh
mesh = pymesh.load_mesh("cube.stl");

I got error like this
mesh_B = pymesh.load_mesh("cube.stl");
AttributeError: module 'pymesh' has no attribute 'load_mesh'

please help me to fix this error...and guide me how to install and setup pymesh

Thankyou...

Comment: There is no `load_mesh` anywhere in the repository: https://github.com/search?q=user%3Ataxpon+load_mesh

Comment: I couldn't understand please give any example

Comment: **There is no `load_mesh`** in pymesh. This is an example of loading data: https://github.com/taxpon/pymesh#load-data